# Passing arguments as an array without .apply()

Tags: javascript

I am try to find out if there is a way to pass arguments to a javascript function as an array, without using the .apply method. The code would look something like this from a user's perspective:

```
var args = [1, 2, 3, 4];
doSomething(args);
```

Note that `doSomething()` will not always be the same function, so I cannot write it to use an array of arguments. Ideally, this should work for any function, and I guess what I am trying to do is essentially convert an array into an arguments-array-like object.

I was thinking that I may be able to set the functions arguments object like this:

```
function.arguments = otherArguments;
```

But I don't know *when* I would have to do that (wouldn't I have to somehow do it once the function started executing but before it actually did anything with its arguments?)

The reason I am trying to do this is because I am trying to write my own .apply function for learning purposes. Is this possible?

Comment: @Rocket I am trying to write my own .apply() method, the problem I am having is that I don't know how to pass arguments to a function as an array.

Comment: `apply` exists for a reason.  There is no way to make your own version, short of `doSomething(args[0], args[1], args[2], ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way around. One tool for one functionality, and the one of choice is [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

If you need to write your own function that does not use `apply`, you would need to use eval:

```
function apply(fn, thisObj, args) {
    var obj = {fn: fn};
    var str = "obj.fn(";
    for (var i=0; i<args.length; i++)
         str += (i?',':'') + "args["+i+"]";
    str += ");";
    return eval(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not recommending this at all, but if you wanted to be insane, you could probably dynamically generate a curry method for the arity of the function that you are invoking, and then invoke the resulting curry in a loop:

```
function func(a,b,c,d) {
  console.log([a,b,c,d]);
  return "Return Value";
}

// Using a static 4 argument curry.
function curry4(f) {
  return function(a) {
    return function(b) {
      return function(c) {
        return function(d) {
          return f(a,b,c,d);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var args = [1,2,3,4];
for(var i=0,f=curry4(func);i<func.length;i++) { f = f(args[i]); }
console.log(f); // f is return value of `func`
```

See [here](http://jsbin.com/exised/5/edit) for example that supports up to 12 optional arguments.

But this road probably leads to madness....

Comment: Thank you. I understand now that there is no standard way to do this, but that's a pretty creative solution, kudos for that.

Comment: I don't think this is a solution at all. It is limited to (exactly) 4 arguments, and that would have been much easier without that semi-currying function.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention:

if you use setTimeout you can pass params:

```
    setTimeout( _function_name_, delay, param1,param2,param3...)
```

this way the params are passed to the function without using apply